# Mousemove event blocked by occluding SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have an SVG element with a mousemove event, showing the coordinate of the pointer. When the the mouse moves over an occluding element, the mousemove event is blocked. I need to make the event propagate to the original element.

I have tried changing the `pointer-events` attribute, but this effects all mouse events, and I need the occluding elements to respond other events. Any suggestions.

Comment: a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help

Comment: Put the Mouse Event Listener in a common ancestor Element...

Comment: You could possibly put the handler on the svg and then use getElementFromPoint change pointer-events temporarily and repeat for next object until you hit the SVG, then put pointer-events back on. May be less expensive. Without code it's hard to know.

Comment: Just thinking, there may also be a way if the mousemove is part of a drag (ie the start of a drag, you turn off pointer-events for other elements and put the class back after the drag has finished)

Comment: Hi Ian, the particular problem I was solving was to display the cursor position in local coordinates, when over a background rectangle, while manipulating objects on top. This was easy to implement by catching the event at a common join. I don't have a problem with drag operations because I use only "selected" objects and handlers. For the selection, which happens via a click or region rectangle. Your tutorial was useful here.

Comment: @Jeromanda X, indeed! Unfortunately, my code base is too complex to allow for a meaningful example.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a method of addressing this would be to tie all your events to the container/parentNode in which your svg and the occluding elements reside - logging the mouse position within that 'outer' element against the '[bounding Client Rectangles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)' properties of the child elements within it.

Without a code sample in the question it is difficult know exactly what would be required, but the principle might follow along these lines...

```
<!-- HTML sample -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="elem1" class="occluded">Element #1</div>
    <div id="elem2" class="occluded">Element #2</div>
    <div class="fullWidthHeightOverlay"></div>
</div>
<div id="eventLog"></div>
```

Let's say the `#container` has a width and height, the `.occluded` elements float within that layer but underneath the `.fullWidthHeightOverly` element (which if I have understood your question correct plays the role of your SVG).  `#eventLog` is something to attach a behaviour to later.

Let's also assume that we want to log the mouse position relative to the outer `#container` layer to make 'click' behaviours available when the mouse is over either of the `.occluded` elements.  (I hope that's clear?)

First we need to attach some events to `#container` - in this case, one for mouse-positions and one for clicks.

```
/* SIMPLE SELECTOR - '#id' */
function $(a){
    $.b = $.b || {};
    if (void 0 === $.b[a]) $.b[a] = document.getElementById(a.slice(1));
    return $.b[a];
}

var elem1, elem2;

/* ! */
function addEvents() {
    $('#container').addEventListener('mousemove', logMousePos, false);
    $('#container').addEventListener('click', occludedClick, false);
}
```

You'll see I've also created a couple of variables we can assign the `.occluded` element to.

Next we need the `logMousePos()` and `occludedClick()` functions in which to log the positional properties of the two `.occluded` elements relative to the mouse-position on the `.fullWidthHeightOverly` layer 'above' them, and then initiate some simple behaviours, E.G...

```
function logMousePos(e) {
    var e1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect(),
        e2 = elem2.getBoundingClientRect(),
        e1CL = elem1.classList,
        e2CL = elem2.classList;

    /* is mouse inside #elem1 ? */
    if (check.X(e.clientX, e1) && check.Y(e.clientY, e1)) {
        /* if no 'over' class add it... */
        if (!e1CL.contains('over')) e1CL.add('over');
    } else {
        /* ...if 'over' class remove it */
        if (e1CL.contains('over')) e1CL.remove('over');
    }

    /* is mouse inside #elem2 ? */
    if (check.X(e.clientX, e2) && check.Y(e.clientY, e2)) {
        if (!e2CL.contains('over')) e2CL.add('over');
    } else {
        if (e2CL.contains('over')) e2CL.remove('over');
    }
}

function occludedClick(e) {
    var e1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect(),
        e2 = elem2.getBoundingClientRect(),
        e1CL = elem1.classList,
        e2CL = elem2.classList;

    /* was mouse clicked inside #elem1 or #elem2 or not ? */
    if (check.X(e.clientX, e1) && check.Y(e.clientY, e1)) {
        $('#eventLog').textContent = 'Element #1 pseudo-Clicked';
    } else if (check.X(e.clientX, e2) && check.Y(e.clientY, e2)) {
        $('#eventLog').textContent = 'Element #2 pseudo-Clicked';
    } else {
        $('#eventLog').textContent = '';
    }
 }
```

..and there you'll notice I'm referring to some `check()` Object methods to, erm, check if the mouse is within the 'boundingClientRect' of either `.occluded` element.

```
var check = {
    X: function(x, el) {
        return (x > el.left && x < el.right);
    },
    Y: function(y, el) {
        return (y > el.top && y < el.bottom);
    }
};
```

Then it's just a matter of initialising the variables and adding the event listeners...

```
(function init() {
    addEvents();
    elem1 = $('#elem1');
    elem2 = $('#elem2');
}());
```

You can find a JSFIDDLE of the whole thing  [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/qn8wf7pL/).

I hope that gives you enough to be able to apply the principle in your particular case.

:)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the key ideas of Brian Peacock's excellent and detailed suggestion:
It seems the problems is that the graphical order of svg elements (what goes behind what) does not follow the DOM hierarchy, so the normal bubbling of events cannot be used directly. Thus, one must capture the event at a common high point and pragmatically search for the elements under the point.

As a general point of discussion (excuse me for this here), it should be noted that this not an optimal solution in many cases. For example, when rapidly occurring events are captured, such as `mousemove`, when there are many element in the SVG, and when fast response is needed for smooth GUI, the strategy may be too computationally expensive. It will be great if better event handling system is included in the SVG specs and included in the browsers, where everything can be done by the engine. This will significantly improve the ability to have pure-SVG GUIs.

Comment: Indeed.  If only the implementation of SVG2 recommendations wasn't so patchy.  But this is a matter for another question on another day.  :)